# Random point outside of a set bounds?

Tags: actionscript-3, random

I want to generate a point (x,y) that is outside of my screen. The reason for this is I want to tween an object towards the outside of the screen, and the reason for tweening rather than just giving it a random X and Y velocity is because for this instance tweening using greensock is simpler than creating an update loop.

So, what is an elegant way to generate that number? My current solution is crude and doesn't allow for things to tween towards corners.

```
var quad:int = irand(1, 4); //generates a random integer between and including the min and max
var maxX:Number = frame.width;
var minX:Number = -frame.width;
var maxY:Number = frame.height;
var minY:Number = -frame.height;

if (quad == 1) //top
{
    maxY = -frame.height;
    minY = -frame.height - 50;
}
else if (quad == 2) //left
{
    maxX = -frame.width;
    minX = -frame.width - 50;
}
else if (quad == 3) //bottom
{
    maxY = frame.height + 50;
    minY = frame.height;
}
else if (quad == 4) //right
{
    maxX =frame.width + 50;
    minX = frame.width;
}

//first param is duration in seconds
//rand generates a number between the given values      
objectToTween.tweenTo(rand(1,2), { 
                        x: rand(minX, maxX),
                        y: rand(minY, maxY),
                        repeat: -1,
                        yoyo: false,
                        scaleX: 1,
                        scaleY: 1,
                        delay: rand(0,1),
                        ease: Quad.easeIn});
```

So hopefully it's clear that this solution picks a random direction and tweens the object towards that direction. I'm wondering if there is a way to generate a random number between two given ranges. (such as, between -100 and 100, but excluding -50 through 50) and then applying that for 2 dimensions

Answer (score 0):

### what you want

So you have a rectangular frame f:

```
┌───┐
│   │
│ f │
│   │
└───┘
```

and a rectangular bounding box of an object o to be tweened to the outside of f:

```
┌─────┐
│  o  │
└─────┘
```

*the outside of f* is a position of o in which both f and o touch each other but do not overlap.

Some such valid target positions of o are shown below:

```
      ┌───┐
      │   │
      │ f ├─────┐  1
      │   │  o  │
      └───┴─────┘

      ┌───┐
      │   │
      │ f │
      │   │        2
  ┌───┴─┬─┘
  │  o  │
  └─────┘

┌─────┐
│  o  ├───┐
└─────┤   │        3
      │ f │
      │   │
      └───┘

     ┌─────┐
     │  o  │
     └┬───┬┘
      │   │        4
      │ f │
      │   │
      └───┘
```

Due to the contact of o and f, one side of o is always shared with f. For the above cases, that is

1. f's right is o's left
2. f's bottom is o's top
3. f's left is o's right
4. f's top is o's bottom

In the edge cases (pun intended), two edges are shared, that is, there is one corner point shared (from example 3, shifting o up a little):

```
┌─────┐
│  o  │
└─────┼───┐ 
      │   │
      │ f │
      │   │
      └───┘
```

o cannot go any further up or to the left. Keep in mind the definition of *the outside of f* that I stated above which is perfectly adequate and a lot simpler than "the infinity of space excluding the rectangle f".

If you shift o over to the right, you get the maximum of the x position (the right most position):

```
          ┌─────┐
          │  o  │
      ┌───┼─────┘
      │   │
      │ f │
      │   │
      └───┘
```

I hope this illustrates that at least one dimension is always predetermined by what sides are touching each other and the other is chosen at random from within the limits. At those limits (minimum and maximum) the two frames will only touch each other at the corners.

There's your problem:

```
x: rand(minX, maxX),
y: rand(minY, maxY),
```

instead, first set 1 dimension of o randomly to one of the cases represented in the 4 examples above. Either

- x is determined by either f's left or
  right (also depending on width and registration point of o), or
- y is determined by either f's top or bottom (also depending on heihgt and registration point of o)

the other one is chosen at random from with **in** the limits.

### what you need

There's so much randomisation going on that it is hardly justifiable to put that much effort into determining a target position.

Consider an alternative approach. Determine a circle around f, that will guarantee to be outside of f. Then randomly determine an angle (direction) and tween according to that. This will make the tweens appear slightly different, because the duration they are visible varies depending on the direction (angle), but this difference will be barely noticeable.

Comment: before you ask: ┼ ┤┬ ┴ ├ │─ ┐└ ┘┌

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your answer but It seems like you're misunderstanding my question (be that my bad or not). The objects are sprites. I tween them from the center of the screen (they are on a transform on the screen, so their 0,0 is dead center of the screen). I need them to tween to either side of the OUTSIDE of the screen, so they can go literally anywhere outside, but I chose to keep it within 50 pixels of the screen for consistency. So essentially, my rangeX excludes negative half the screen width through positive half my screen width. So the range is some arbitrary number outside

Comment: @PremierBromanov my answer is exactly answering that: finding positions for o that are outside of f. Where f is your screen and o is the bounding box of your Sprite. My answer is thus independent of how your registration points are located. If you want to add a padding of 50 pixels around f, simply add 25 to all sides of f. Could you please elaborate on what's unclear to you?

Comment: I guess I dont understand how your answer is any different from my current solution

Comment: @PremierBromanov you stated in your question that your solution `doesn't allow for things to tween towards corners`. My solution picks randomly from all possible solutions that touch the frame/screen. Please also note that I provided a second solution, see"**what you need**", that is certainly a lot more elegant, if elegance is your main concern.